# How to connect two ABB plcs with cp635 HMI?

Tags: tags, ip, display, ethernet, plc

I want to connect two PLCs ABB PM592 with HMI CP635 via ethernet? I will assign the same ip addresses to both plcs and will connect the ethernet port of each plc with ethernet port of HMI. Will it work?
Will the both ethernet ports of CP635 HMI can work on same ip addresses? Because if I assign different IPs to each plc then i will also have to import tags for each ip with different name but we can assign single tag to one object in HMI design.

Waiting for reply

TIA :)

Answer (score 0):

The PLCs will need seperate IP addresses

The solution is to run two protocols.
To save having to retype all tags, how can export to xml file then import to the new protocol. panel builder 600 will automatically rename by appending a number to the duplicate tags.